# How to get text of hyperlink of webview on long press in android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, hyperlink

I am building an android application where a webpage( like "https://www.youtube.com/" ) is loaded on a webView. Now in that WebPage, there are some Hyperlink's.

Once an user long press on any of Hyperlink a list open and there are many feature's like copy link, open link in next tap and copy text. Now the issue that I am facing. I am not able to copy the text on that anchor tag where user long press.

I need when any user long press on any hyperlink and select copy text that hyperlink text should be copied. Is there any I can achieve this?

My long press return title and url.

I had refer a lot of link like [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182079/implement-copy-link-text-feature-in-the-app)

Comment: obviously you will get an event, try getting the `value` of the event.target ?

Comment: @Jeffin how can you help little?

Comment: Right now I am not getting any event on long click of hyperlink

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html this not working ?

Comment: I am able to write OnLongClickListener on hyperlink I need a value on that event

Comment: [this will work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203282/getting-link-text-of-the-link-displayed-in-webview/#59781617)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to listen for `View.OnLongClickListener`. You can do that very easily by setting a listener on the `WebView`. Listener has to return a `Boolean`, return `false` if you want the copy, cut and paste on text selection or return `true`

```
webView.setOnLongClickListener { view ->
    // run things on long click on any element in the webview
    return@setOnLongClickListener false
}
```

Then create a `Handler`

```
val handler = Handler { message ->
    val bundle = message.data

    for (key in bundle.keySet()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "KEY: $key, VALUE: ${bundle.get(key)}")
    }
    val linkText = bundle.get("title") // here is your link text   

    return@Handler true
}
```

Now you need to obtain the message (this code has to go inside the `OnLongClickListener`)

```
val message = handler.obtainMessage()
webView.requestFocusNodeHref(message)
```

Copying text to the `ClipBoard` got a little bit complicated.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    val clipboardManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as android.content.ClipboardManager
    val clipData = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("text label", "text to clip")
    clipboardManager.primaryClip = clipData
} else {
    val clipboardManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as android.text.ClipboardManager
    clipboardManager.text = "text to clip"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm doing the same thing today.

finally I use bellow method:

1.Saving whole html content in onPageFinished().

2. Use WebView.HitTestResult.getExtra() to get url.
3. then substring the text among href link tag.

A clunky way, hope it can help you.